# Run SQL query from cron

Tags: sql, cron

I'd like to run a SQL query via cron. I figured I'd create a `.sql` file and call it from a script that I place in the cron folder. The query is relatively large and not written by me, so I'd prefer to not have to re-create it in PHP.

Can anyone provide some assistance? I am not exactly clear on how to run the SQL query from the script. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Just for some background info, the query is intended to grab data from multiple tables and organize it in a csv file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I ended up using was to put the query in a "here document". This bash script was then implemented with cron. For more information, check out this link:
http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/3078

And just in case that link goes dead, here's a snippet of the sample code:

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash
# execute some bash scripting commands here

mysql mydatabase <<SQL_ENTRY_TAG_1
SELECT * 
  FROM mytable 
  WHERE somecondition='somevalue';
SQL_ENTRY_TAG_1

# execute other bash scripting commands here

mysql mydatabase <<SQL_ENTRY_TAG_2
SELECT *
  FROM myothertable
  WHERE someothercondition='someothervalue';
SQL_ENTRY_TAG_2
```

Answer (score 3):

Each database has a command line client tool

For MySQL, see `man mysql`

comand to add in cron something like this

`cat /dir/query.sql|mysql database -u user -ppass >result`

---

For PHP you can use file IO to read query, after that use string variable instead of the query in your requests.

Comment: What is the reason for `cat` and `>result`?

Comment: cat send file to stdout. after that pipe send all that to mysql clietn like u do when type that using keyboard. >result mean send output to file "result". better use full path. see bash-shell articles for farther understanding.

Comment: The SQL query that I'm running exports to a .csv file and takes about 5 minutes to complete. When I used your command, it finished immediately and the `result` file had the `man mysql` page in it. Something is not working properly.

Comment: @arheops: Wouldn't `mysql database -u user -ppass </dir/query.sql >result` work as well? :)

Comment: sure. but i see no real difference in it. it is just other notation ;)

Comment: If my query typically exports a .csv file, will it still be exported using this command? I don't need anything output to `result`, I just need the .csv file.

Comment: u need give mysql params, so ur query result will looks like csv file. see man mysql for more params.